# Solution of differential equation related to Normal density

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normal-distribution

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be the standard normal density, $$\phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Given $0<\sigma\le 1$. I wish to know whether there exists an explicit solution $\alpha$ satisfying the differential equation 
$$\alpha''(u) [\phi(u) + \frac 1\sigma \phi(u/\sigma)] - \alpha'(u) [u\phi(u) + \frac 1{\sigma^3} u\phi(u/\sigma)] - \alpha(u)  [\phi(u) + \frac 1{\sigma^3} \phi(u/\sigma)] = \frac 1{\sigma^5} u\phi(u/\sigma).$$

For $\sigma=1$, I got that the explicit solution for the above differential equation is $\alpha(u)= -\frac 14 u + (a + b \Phi(u))/\phi(u)$ where $\Phi(u)=\int_{-\infty}^u\phi(x)dx.$ However, when $\sigma<1$ it really makes difficult in finding the solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: You let $\phi$ be defined as above then you seek a solution $\phi$ to the equation?  I think you have used $\phi$ to mean two different things.

Comment: Thanks @InfiniteDifferenceMethod for your respond. What I meant is $\alpha$. I have edited there.

Comment: @GlenO: Do you mean that $-\frac14$ can be replaced by any constant $A$?

Comment: @Jlamprong - I must apologise, I was mistaken; I thought $u$ was a solution to the homogeneous equation, and it's not. For some reason, I was thinking that $(u\alpha(u))'=0$ for $\alpha=Au$. I have removed the original comment, as I was wrong.

Comment: @GlenO: No problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

After correcting the mistake in my first answer, the method of solving fails. So my answer must be withdrawn.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JJacquelin for your help. Let me study your solution please. +1

Comment: I tried to plug $\sigma=1$ in your solution. But, the result is different with mine. Could you tell me why?

Comment: And I have verified that my solution for $\sigma=1$ is valid.

Comment: Yes, your solution is valid. Mine not. After correction, my method of solving fails completly. So, I withdraw my first answer. I am awfully sorry to have given a false sense of hope of solving the problem.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your time.